# Genealogy & Family History SE is turning 10!

Tags: discussion

Thank you to the whole community for making this a great site to get your Genealogy & Family History questions answered.

The Overflow (Stack Overflow blog) will feature us along with the other sites turning 10 around the same time, in a post similar to
[Celebrating the Stack Exchange sites that turned ten years old in Spring 2022](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/06/27/celebrating-the-stack-exchange-sites-that-turned-ten-years-old-in-spring-2022/?_ga=2.119712200.1569164953.1665095066-299304934.1562909941).

We need to provide a short blurb about our site and, if you want to contribute, here are some prompts:

- What have been your favorite or most helpful posts?
- What do you like best about our community?
- What do you come here to learn?

Answer (score 3):

> What do you like best about our community?

Genealogical research often means crossing national borders to find records of interest. Foreign language, writing style and (historical) expressions are a major obstacle when attempting to interpret these sometimes almost illegible records. With this helpful international community, such obstacles can be more easily overcome.

Answer (score 2):

This is a late answer, but I wanted to give a tip of the hat for a favorite post:  [What "hidden" clues are there in the GRO Indexes of births and deaths?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/10355/1006)

This Q/A is one of my favorites because it 'recovers' information which was lost when you use the digital version of the original printed index. So many times, I see people fail to make full use of a printed resource that is scanned (e.g. failing to search for the page of abbreviations when reading a page out of a city directory).

This Q/A is a good example of what I come here to learn.  Genealogy and Family History Stack Exchange doesn't have to be simply a place to get an answer to a single question. It can be a place to learn new skills which will improve our research across many different ancestral lines.

What do I like best about our commnity? The emphasis on showing our research effort and solving specific problems we have in our research.

When we focus on the historical records we are using, and learn to understand them better, the results have a much broader reach than a single solution to a single question.